# java: make program wait until transition is finished

Tags: java, transition

I've been writing a method to switch two images. This method is called in a mouse drag-and-drop event and is followed by another method that lets images drop down a few positions (I'm talking about a sort of candy crush mechanism).
In my case, the transition in the second method starts before the switch is done, which is why you can barely see the switch.
What I'm looking for is a way to make the program wait until the first transition is finished before it steps into the next method. Thread.sleep() isn't working for me since it stops the switch animation as well, and I don't know how to use the transition.setOnFinished() properly within my switch method without causing an infinite loop.

This is part of my switch method:

```
    public void animateSwitch(int xFirst, int yFirst, int xLast, int yLast) {
```

/*...*/

```
    ParallelTransition allMovements = new ParallelTransition();

    TranslateTransition tt = new  TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(FALL_TIME_PER_ROW), getNodeFromGridPane(grdPane, xFirst, yFirst));

    TranslateTransition tt2 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(FALL_TIME_PER_ROW), getNodeFromGridPane(grdPane, xLast, yLast));

    Image old = iv1.getImage();
    iv1.setImage(iv2.getImage());
    iv1.setTranslateX(iv2.getX());
    iv1.setTranslateY(iv2.getY());
    iv2.setImage(old);
    iv2.setTranslateX(iv1.getX());
    iv2.setTranslateY(iv1.getY());
    if (xFirst == xLast) {
        tt.toYProperty().set(0);
        tt.toXProperty().set(tt.getFromX());
        if (yFirst < yLast) {
            tt.fromYProperty().set(rowHeight);
            tt2.fromYProperty().set(-rowHeight);
        }
        else {
            tt.fromYProperty().set(-rowHeight);
            tt2.fromYProperty().set(rowHeight);
        }
        tt2.toYProperty().set(0);
        tt2.toXProperty().set(tt2.getFromX());
    }
    else if (yFirst == yLast) {
        tt.toXProperty().set(0);
        tt.toYProperty().set(tt.getFromY());
        if (xFirst < xLast) {
            tt.fromXProperty().set(rowWidth);
            tt2.fromXProperty().set(-rowWidth);
        }
        else {
            tt.fromXProperty().set(-rowWidth);
            tt2.fromXProperty().set(rowWidth);
        }
        tt2.toXProperty().set(0);
        tt2.toYProperty().set(tt2.getFromY());
    }

    allMovements.getChildren().add(tt);
    allMovements.getChildren().add(tt2);
    allMovements.play();  
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can make a `boolean isFinished` which will be `true` after switch is done and make second method to check and wait until `isFinished` is `true`.

Comment: How do I do that without making the whole program stop?

Comment: `while( !isFinished ){ //nothing }` here will be stuck until `isFinished` is `true` . You just need to have access at `isFinished` from where put this `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the onFinished event handler using `allMovements.setOnFinished(eventHandler);` Here `eventHandler` is an object that implements the `EventHandler` interface.

EDIT:
I skipped past the part where you don't know how to prevent an infinite loop using this solution. You can use two different eventHandlers to do the different parts. The first calls the second when it finishes. The second doesn't need to call the first, so you will not get into a loop.

Comment: The second method does not follow directly, there are other methods from other classes that check for a pattern befor the second transition is called, and all of those are called inside my FXMLDocumentController. I can't call the second transition method from the first because for that I would need to import classes I do not want to import (or am not allowed to).

Comment: @TheDawnAvenue Could you show the code where you call the two methods? I find it hard to give a solution without knowing how exactly you use it.

Comment: gui.animateSwitch(positions[0][0], positions[0][1], positions[1][0], 
                positions[1][1]); 
                do {
                    gameLogic.deletePattern(ptrn);
                    ptrn = gameLogic.lookForPattern();
                } while (ptrn != null);

deletePattern() then calls the second function for each column where it finds a pattern

Comment: If you add an EventHandler argument to your `animateSwitch` method, you can have the followup code executed in the EventHandler and then set it using `allMovements.setOnFinished(eventHandler);` in the `animateSwitch` method.